# Rename Multiple Files in a Directory Replacing Certain Characters on PHP

Tags: php

I have a directory with lots of files in them.
I just want to delete single quotes and replace the ampersand (&) with "and" in the FILENAME to all the files.
Is it possible in php ?

Comment: Yes it is! Or do you want us to write your code for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
You have to open the directory and rename the files one by one.

```
if ($fh = opendir('filepath')) 
{
    while (false !== ($oldName = readdir($fh))) 
    {
        if ($oldName !== $newName = str_replace("&", "and", $oldName))
        {
            rename($oldName, $newName);
        }
    }
    closedir($fh);
}
```

Comment: i overread the first part. you also have to replace single quotes with `""`